# PHP: Add line to text file from URL variable

Tags: php, url, variables, text, edit

I have *never* done any php, but I am trying to do something very simple.

So basically what I am trying to achieve is that add a line to already existing text file from url. To make it easier to understand, here's an example:

I have text file, what contains the following:

```
127.0.0.1-USA-Admin
127.0.0.1-SWE-Admin
127.0.0.1-CA-Admin
```

so after I go to link:

**example.com/index.php?ip=127.0.0.1&Co=USA&Usr=Admin**

The text file would be updated, and it would look like this:

```
127.0.0.1-USA-Admin
127.0.0.1-SWE-Admin
127.0.0.1-CA-Admin
127.0.0.1-USA-Admin
```

How to achieve this?

I am sorry if it's a beginner question, but I've never done anything in PHP.
I assume it has something to do with `$_GET` -thing.

Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say that the text file name is textfile.txt. Bellow is the php code:

```
<?php
    $fh = fopen('textfile.txt', 'a');
    fwrite($fh, $_GET['ip'].'-'.$_GET['Co'].'-'.$_GET['Usr']."\n\r");
    fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, worked fine. All other worked too, just had to add newline chars to beginning & end.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is,

```
$ip = $_GET["ip"];
$co = $_GET["co"];
$usr = $_GET["usr"];

$file = "yourfile.txt";
file_put_contents($file, "$ip-$co-$usr", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

For more information, please check 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

You've not given any code to correct/fix.  And I'm not going to write it for you.

Here are the functions you'll most likely need:

You'll need a couple of functions.
**file_put_contents**  http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php
To append to the file.

**parse_url** http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

If you get stuck, paste your code into your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file_put_contents`:

```
file_put_contents( 
    'your-file.ext', 
    sprintf( "%s-%s-%s", $_GET['ip'], $_GET['Co'], $_GET['Usr'] ), 
    FILE_APPEND
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code should be

```
$contents = file("myfile.txt");
$contents[] = $_GET["ip"]."-".$_GET["Co"]."-".$_GET["Usr"];
file_put_contents('myfile.txt', $contents);
```